# How to find shared drive by name without domain admin access

Tags: google-drive-api

How can I get the ID of a shared folder when I know it's name, without using `useDomainAdminAccess=true`?

When impersonating a non-admin user with a service account, I can list all available shared folders with `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives`. But strangely I'm not allowed to use the query string `name = 'folderName'`.

One solution would be to retrieve the list all folders and pick the entry with the desired name from the returned list. But that is a waste of resources.

I also cannot search for the root folder of the shared drive (using `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files`), because all root folders of shared drives have the fixed name `"Drive"`.

Comment: can you edit your question and include [example] including the results you are seeing and what you would like to see.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this is simply not possible.*

#### More Information:

As you have already noted, Most query terms require `useDomainAdminAccess=true`. This is pointed out in the [Search for shared drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-shareddrives) documentation, along with links to query terms and operators. From [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms#drive_properties) you can see that the only Shared drive-specific query terms are the following:

> | Query term | Valid Operators | Usage | Required `useDomainAdminAccess` setting |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `createdTime` | `<=`, `<`, `=`, `!=`, `>`, `>=` | Date when the shared drive was created. Use RFC 3339 format, default timezone is UTC, e.g., **2012-06-04T12:00:00-08:00**. | `true` |
> | `hidden` | `=`, `!=` | Specifies whether or not the shared drive is hidden. Can be either `true` or `false`. | `false` |
> | `memberCount` | `<=`, `<`, `=`, `!=`, `>`, `>=` | Number of users and groups that are members of the shared drive. Takes a numerical value. | `true` |
> | `name` | `contains`, `=`, `!=` | Name of the shared drive. Surround with single quotes '. Escape single quotes in queries with ', such as `'Valentine\'s Day'`. | `true` |
> | `organizerCount` | `<=`, `<`, `=`, `!=`, `>`, `>=` | Number of users and groups that are organizers of the shared drive. Takes a numerical value. | `true` |

Where ***only*** the parameter `hidden` is able to be used without the `useDomainAdminAccess` set to be true.

The only workaround here is as you have suggested - make a Drives:list query and filter locally for the Drive ID based on the name of the Drive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this is an error in the API design. There is no reason why a filter with the name should require domain admin privileges.

Comment: @Christiand'Heureuse I suggest filing a feature request to have this available without admin privileges, you can do that at [https://issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com)